# SwiftUI Splitview the DetailView not in Navigation?

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, splitview

I try to create a splitview in SwiftUI, and I have 2 issues
1. the Detail-View not showing in the navigation
2. if I go to Detail-View from master view it shows in navigation (Navigation top bar), but when it goes to next page, back button not work

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ListView()
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}


struct ListView: View {
    let menuItems = [MenuItem(name: "Login"),
                     MenuItem(name: "KS & Token"),
                     MenuItem(name: "Household & Domain"),
                     MenuItem(name: "Register")]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(self.menuItems, id:\.id) { item in

                    NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(menuItem: item)){
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }

        .navigationBarTitle(Text("User Menu"))
    }
}
```

the issue is:
1. DetailView() not showing Navigation top bar
2. in LoginView, when I go to next page with NavigationLink, the app does not show back button, and also add it by code, not help